# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\gamma_n\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=1$ - any theorems that reduce the workload for this?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, exponential-function

> Let $(\gamma_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\Bbb R$ be a sequence of reals that converges to $0$. Let $x\in\Bbb R$ be fixed. Then show that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\gamma_n\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=1$$

As a beginner to real analysis, the statement seems obvious but there are no immediate ways (as far as I know) to rigorously show this. I will present my own proof, and although I am of course interested in whether my solution is correct, I am mainly focused on the existence of theorems about double-limits or nested sequences like this, because any such theorem would probably address this question immediately. For example, I recently asked a question here about my proof of the non-uniform convergence of $\sin(1/x)$. A commenter and answerer noted that I immediately know that all uniformly continuous functions map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, and if I had known that at the time I could have saved myself an hour of work! Such theorems are of great interest to me, and a list of them is hard to find. The main issue in this problem is that the expression is not $e^{0\cdot x}$ at any one point, and we have two converging sequences nested in one another: $\gamma_n\to0,(\cdots)^n\to e^{\gamma_n\cdot x}$

My work:

> By known results about $e$, $\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\,\exists N_1\in\Bbb N:\forall n\gt N_1,\,|\left(1+\gamma_n\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-\exp(\gamma_n\cdot x)|\lt\varepsilon$. Additionally, we have that $\forall\delta\gt0,\,\exists N_2\in\Bbb N:\forall n\gt N_2,\,|\gamma_n|\lt\delta$ since $(\gamma_n)\to0$.
>
> Choose some $0\lt\delta\ll x$, and some arbitrary $\varepsilon\gt0$, and choose $N\gt\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ where $N_1,N_2$ depend on $\delta,\,\varepsilon$ as before. Let $L_n=\left(1+\gamma_n\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$. It is sufficient to show that $\forall n\gt N$: $$1-\varepsilon\lt L_n\lt1+\varepsilon$$
>
> Let $n\gt N$. By the above, we can write: $$\exp(\gamma_n\cdot x)-\varepsilon\lt L_n\lt\exp(\gamma_n\cdot x)+\varepsilon$$ By the increasing property of $\exp$ and assumption on $\gamma$, we have $-\delta\lt\gamma_n\lt\delta$ and we have: $$\exp(-\delta\cdot x)-\varepsilon\lt L_n\lt\exp(\delta\cdot x)+\varepsilon$$
>
> Taking limits as $\delta\to0,\,\varepsilon\to0$, we know that such an $N$ will always exist, and consequently we can write, by the continuity of $\exp$: $$1-(\varepsilon\to0)\lt\lim_{n\to\infty}L_n\lt1+(\varepsilon\to0)$$ Proving that $(L_n)\to1$ as required, via the squeeze theorem.

Before coming up with this, I had tried for some time with meaningless binomial analyses. I hope my more straightforward approach here is correct, but as I said before, the existence of theorems about what I am probably erroneously calling "nested sequences" is important to me as a real analysis student. Many thanks to anyone who can provide insight on this.

Note: This question was marked as hard in Courant's Differential and Integral Calculus textbook, Volume $1$, which prompted me to doubt that my proof was rigorous.

Comment: $$\ldots\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+\gamma_n\frac{x}{n}\right)=0\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}n\gamma_n\frac{x}{n}=0$$ because of continuity of $z\mapsto\log z$ around $z=1$, and $\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\log(1+z)/z=1$.

Comment: (Which brings up the question about the context - what tools are you *already* "equipped" with?)